# python read data from variable and write to a file (no print) which i wanted to use later as backup data

Tags: python

I am new to python and programming. Starting to try few things for my project..

My problem is as below

```
p=subprocess.Popen(Some command which gives me output],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.wait()
content=p.stdout.readlines()
for line in content:
    filedata=line.lstrip().rstrip()
```

-----> **I want this filedata output to open and save it to a file.**

If i use print filedata it works and gives me exactly what i wanted but i donot want to print and wanted to use this data later.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please take a moment to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) your code, and possibly provide us with a [MCVE]

Comment: what kind of file to which you wanted to save?

Comment: I wanted it to be a text file, Sorry about the formatting. I am trying to copy properly but it dint work as expected.
=================================================== 
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd output),
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.wait()
content=p.stdout.readlines()
for line in content:
    filedata=line.lstrip().rstrip()
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
the filedata need to be written to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in following two ways.

Option one uses more traditional way of file handling, I have used with statement, using with statement you don't have to worry about closing the file

Option two, which makes use of pathlib module and this is new in version 3.4 (I recommend using this)

somefile.txt is the full file path in file system. I've also included documentation links and I highly recommend going through those.

> OPTION ONE

```
p=subprocess.Popen(Some command which gives me output],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.wait()
content=p.stdout.readlines()
for line in content:
    filedata=line.lstrip().rstrip()
    with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(filedata + '\n')
```

[Documentation for The with Statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

> OPTION TWO - For Python 3.4 or above

```
import pathlib 
p=subprocess.Popen(Some command which gives me output],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.wait()
content=p.stdout.readlines()
for line in content:
    filedata=line.lstrip().rstrip()
    pathlib.Path('somefile.txt').write_text(filedata + '\n')
```

[Documentation on Pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: Hello Sulabh, I did try the same and it dint work earlier.. now it works.. Unsure of what mistake I did earlier.. Thanks again however I have another query. The data is formatted properly when I printed but the same is not when output to file.

Comment: which option did you use ?

Comment: Okay, I assume that, you want to write each time on a newline. If that's the formatting issue, change file.write(filedata) to file.write(filedata + '\n'). I've update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes. I did that but in general, when we print, the output is correct and the same way it should dump to the file.. may be I am wrong. Also, If i use 'w' instead of 'a' also the data is not dumped to file.

Comment: you're using a python built-in function. so, it will simply add any content you specify i.e. if you add 'abc' and in next loop counter you add 'xyz' it will write to a file as 'abc' + 'xyz'. so, you need to specify that, you want, 'abc\n'. so, the next content is added to a newline in a file.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. This works and I will try to complete my code and try to investigate why the write function is not working and append is